# Multiple Eventemitter emits synchronous function called in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, callback, angular-event-emitter

```
doSomething(){

this.open.emit() ;
this.close.emit() ;

}
```

As you may think of open and close is output decorator.
I want first it open.emit() when completed it do close.emit()

I am calling doSomething on a (click) event

```
<button (click)="doSomething()">
</button>
```

Comment: what your question specifically?

Comment: I want it the function doSomething() work Synchronously as mentioned. First it do this.open.emit this will emit event (open)=openFunc($event) . WHEN THIS FUNCTION COMPLETED THEN ONLY DO this.close.emit()

Comment: [EventEmitters](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) have no return value. 
You can't "listen/wait" for the result of a function in the parent container like that. You will need to find another way. Could be an @Input you add to notify you when the parent is done. Or move logic to a service to run your function. Many ways to do that.